# Swing Intellij GUIDesigner image disappears if placed in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jpanel

I'm using IntelliJ GUIDesigner.
I have JScrollPanel which contains JPanel.

The idea is that I want to add image to JPanel and to have it load at full size so I can use scrollers to move around and see whole image.

And My problem is that it paints itself alright if I won't change the size of JPanel. But the moment I'm chaning JPanel size it just repaints itself to orginal state (I suppose, IntelliJ hides a lot of code from me).

The code is:

```
private JPanel panel1;
private JButton button1;
private JPanel drawingPanel;

public MainPanel(){
    button1.addActionListener(e -> {
        JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
        File chosenFile;

        if(openFile.showSaveDialog(panel1) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            chosenFile = openFile.getSelectedFile();
            drawImage(chosenFile);
        }
    });
}

private void drawImage(File file){
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        //Works OK if line belowed is removed, but doesn't adjust size so I can't scroll.
        drawingPanel.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        drawingPanel.paintComponents(g);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As I wrote in comment, if the line below the comment is removed then I can load the image and it shows OK but it's too big and I can't see whole image.
If I add the line then it just clears everything and I can't see nothing.

This is important - I need to get the image to show in full size.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

> I have JScrollPanel which contains JPanel.

Don't do custom painting.

Just create a JLabel and add the label to the viewport of the scroll pane. Then when you want to change the image you use the `setIcon(...)` method of the JLabel and the label will automatically repaint itself and scrollbars will appear if necessary.

Comment: But that's the thing. I need to do custom painting. This is for university. There are a lot of things here and one of those are that the panel should adjust if the image is bigger than the panel. I need to do that.

Comment: @user3212350, Your painting code is wrong, you NEVER invoke the painting methods directly. You can invoke repaint() to tell a component to repaint itself. If you really need to do custom painting then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples. The key is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of your image so the panels preferred size can be determined properly.

Comment: Yes, but this is the problem. IntelliJ doesn't allow me to use custom classes inside GUIDesigner or I don't know how to do that. I can't override JPanel paintComponent

Comment: I'm sure the tool does allow you to override methods otherwise the tool would not be very useful. This is why I never use a tool to create the GUI, so I can't help you. I would rather spend my time learning how to use Java, not learning how to use the tool. What happens when you move to Netbeans or Eclipse?

Comment: This is completely irrelevant. Tools are here to help with life.
I don't want to waste time doing everything in code, doesn't make any sense. I need to focus on things which really are important. There is no way that this is impossible to do in IntelliJ, the problem is I don't know how to do that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can share your IntelliJ GUI forms? Otherwise it's difficult to reproduce the scrolling problem that you're facing. Without the custom painting and using a label as [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) suggested, you can get scrolling working like this:

```
public class MainPanel {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel drawingPanel;
    private JLabel drawingLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainPanel.test();
    }

    private static void test() {
        frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        new MainPanel();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainPanel() {
        initializeGui();
        button1.addActionListener(e -> {
            JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser("[...]");
            File chosenFile;

            if (openFile.showSaveDialog(panel1) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                chosenFile = openFile.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println("chosenFile: " + chosenFile);
                drawImage(chosenFile);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeGui() {
        panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        button1 = new JButton("Open image");
        panel1.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        drawingPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        drawingLabel = new JLabel();
        drawingPanel.add(new JScrollPane(drawingLabel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void drawImage(File file){
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            //Works OK if line below is removed, but doesn't adjust size so I can't scroll.
//            drawingPanel.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
//            Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
//            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
//            drawingPanel.paintComponents(g);

            drawingLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            drawingPanel.validate();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure how easy it is to do something similar with the IntelliJ GUI designer; I do prefer IntelliJ (over Eclipse and NetBeans) but I also prefer to create my Java GUIs in code... ;-)